# Como crear un for o foreach en React para recorrer listas de Radio butons

Tags: reactjs, radiobutton

Estoy creando una Encuesta y necesito recuperar las 72 respuestas las cuales son dadas marcando los radio buttons pero solo e podido recuperar el ultimo que selecciono necesito ayuda si alguien sabe como puedo crear un for o alguna forma de recorre y obtener el nombre , el valor y el id.

```
   //metodo que Guarda la respuesta que se seleccione 
    onchangeRadio = value => {   
        this.setState({ 
           idPregunta: value.target.name,
           idRespuesta: value.target.value,
           idTra: value.target.id
       })
}
```

```html
render() {
        return (
       <div className="row">
       <center>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}  name="myform"> 
        <font size='2'>
        <th>
        <ul className="list-group" >
            {
            this.state.id.map(id => <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" key={id.id}>
            {id.idPregunta}          
            </li>)
            }
        </ul> 
        </th>

        <th>
        <ul className="list-group" >

            {
            this.state.id.map(id => <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" key={id.id}>
            {id.descPregunta}                    
            </li>)
            }
        </ul> 
        </th> 
        </font>

        <font size='2'>
        <th>
        <ul className="list-group" >
            {
            this.state.id.map(id => <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" key={id.id}>
            Siempre <input type="radio" name={id.idPregunta} value={id.resp1} id={id.idTra} 
            onChange={this.onchangeRadio} />              
            </li>)
            }
        </ul> 
        </th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que efectivamente estás guardando en tu estado solo 3 valores, `idPregunta`, `idRespuesta` y `idTra`, cuando deberías guardar un arreglo o un object donde quede la información recopilada de todos los campos.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      //  Defines donde van a ir guardadas tus respuestas. Para este caso yo use
      //  un object, que es más fácil de consultar y guardar en caso que lo
      //  requieras, aunque también podrías usar un array.
      respuestas: {},
    };
  }

  onchangeRadio = (event) => {
    const { name, value, id } = event.target;
    // Haces un spreading sobre un nuevo object, ya que el del state es
    // inmutable
    let respuestas = { ...this.state.respuestas };
    // Modificas/agregas los valores en el nuevo object 
    respuestas[id] = {
      idPregunta: name,
      idRespuesta: value,
    };
    // Y finalmente actualizas tus respuestas con el nuevo object ya modificado
    this.setState({respuestas: respuestas});
  };
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar entonces con ese código cada ves que yo haga click en un radio se almacena en el array

Comment: Perdón pero quisiera saber si podrías ayudarme con una duda que tengo al enviarlos con el método que me distes se envían como objetos y en la base de datos los tengo divididos en 3 campos los cuales son id de la pregunta , la respuesta y el idTra que es el id del trabajador en cuanto al método que me pasaste solo me deja almacenar solo una respuesta

Comment: @Jonathan te sugiero que hagas una nueva pregunta donde puedas explicar tu problema con mayor detalle, ya que no especificas la forma que envías la información, que envías, que se guarda, etc.